# led tv monitor supports 1920 x 1080 Full HD Resolution but on my pc resolutions settings there are no 1080p resolution?

Tags: tv, led, high-definition, 1080p

I have a TCL 19" LED19P21 LED TV according to its specs it should support 1080p resolution but I don't see 1080p resolution on my windows 7 display settings. I have a HD 4670 ati radeon video card and its more than enough to support HD.

1600x1200
1600x900
1440x900
1400x1050
1366x768
1360x1024
and so on
no 1920x1080p

tried every settings and the only acceptable display quality is 1366x768
1440x900 is the next bet but it is much blurry especially the text on screen and edges which is pain in the eyes, so I opt to 1366x768 res.

Comment: Please clarify how you connecting from the video card to the LED TV. Are you using VGA, DVI-I, or HDMI? If you are using any video adapters, explain what adapters you are using. Things like KVM, or any connectors between the video card and LED TV is also important.

Comment: I am using VGA . there is an HDMI port on my monitor and Video card as well but it wont work though.

Comment: I don't think VGA will work for that, I think the real question you should be asking is to how to get the HDMI working.

Comment: my video card is pretty old i suspect that my video card hdmi port is broken. or is there any other reason other than that?

Answer (score 2):

When using VGA, the maximum resolution for your video card is 1600x1200.

Try connecting via DVI-I or HDMI as that will allow for higher resolutions.

Comment: how do i connect via DVI-I? I my monitor don't have a slot for it. will a VGA to DVI-I adapter work?

Comment: No VGA to DVI-I will not work. Max is still 1600x1200. Use HDMI cable then.

Comment: im going to borrow a working HDMI cable and try it? does the HDMI cable will give me more res options?

Comment: Yes, HDMI is preferred since you will get a better picture with digital versus VGA which is analog. Pixel placement will be perfect with HDMI (digital).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the drivers for your video card is installed. You can download yours from here: http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop

Comment: i downloaded it from ati radeon website the latest driver? is it still not it?

Comment: Did you restart your computer after you have installed it?

Comment: with ATI drivers, you have to uninstall all ati products and make sure your computer is running with default microsft display drivers  before installing the ati drivers.

Comment: hi done it but still the same?